# Limit instance lifetime to a single iteration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm working on a web application that uses a couple of services to synchronize data with external resources. The application and the services share the same data layer and use Castle Windsor to implement IoC.

In the web application there is the a PerWebRequest lifestyle which limits the lifetime of an instance to the lifetime of a request. I want to use something similar in the services.
The services are triggered every once in a while to do the synchronization. I want the services and repositories in the datalayer to be singletons within the a single iteration of the service, similar to the PerWebRequest lifestyle in the web application.

What I've come up with is the concept of a *Run*. A run is a single invocation of the synchronization code within the service. That looks like this:

```
   using( _runManager.Run() )
   {
      var sync = _usageRepoFactory.CreateInstance();
      sync.SynchronizeUsage();
   }
```

The implementation of `IRun` will release all instances with the PerRunLifeStyle resolved since it's creation when it is disposed, at the end of the `using` block.
This code looks quite clean, but I wonder if there is a better way of doing this. I have tried using child containers but found these rather 'heavy' after profiling the solution.

Any feedback is welcome. If needed I can post the `IRun` implementation as well.

**Update**

Based on the comments I've cleaned up the code a bit. I've introduced a new service `IRunManager` which is basically a factory for `IRun`. I've also started using a factory to get rid of the ServiceLocator invocation.

Comment: are we talking about WCF services? WCF Facility has per-wcf-operation lifestyle. Also don't use container as service locator!

Comment: @Krzysztof These are 'classic' windows services. I'm not sure what you mean when you say I should not use the container as service locator.

Comment: RE: Service Locator --> See: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Comment: About ServiceLocator; the snippet above is the the 'plumbing' for the service, not API code. This is the only code in the service that is accessing the ServiceLocator directly, so I don't think the service locator anti-pattern applies here. Please let me know if I got this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [contextual lifestyle](http://blog.schuager.com/2010/11/contextual-lifestyle-reloaded.html)